# I wrote this function to find the max elements.But why is my function not returning the correct value in python

Tags: python-2.7

```
def max(*args):
    return sorted(args[-1])

print max([1,3],[1,4],[2,1])
>>>[1,2]
```

I am getting (1,2) as answer which is not even in the list i supplied.I understand it has something to do with [-1].following are the values returned when i tried with 0 ,1 ,2 in place of -1

```
0-->1,3
1-->1,4
2-->1,2
```

Can someone explain what is happening

Answer (score 1):

sorry guys. my bad . I found out that correct code should be:

```
def max(*args):
    return sorted(args)[-1]
```